# Completely backup MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, backups

I'm trying to backup my MediaWiki instance.  I'd like to do it completely, meaning that if the web server exploded suddenly, with the backup files, I can restore the MediaWiki instance completely to its state when the backup was created.   The best reference so far I found is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Fullsitebackup .   Just want to check with experienced MediaWiki administrators if this is up-to-date and complete, or if it's even the best/right reference.

Comment: What about completely downloading your installation...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fullsitebackup` script looks fine but it might not work on all systems. It's dumping the database and it's compressing the files in a tar file.

As with any backup script and system the best way to know if it works is to take the backup, set it up on a fresh machine and see if everything works as usual.

It's worth learning some basic shell scripting if you're managing websites for which you need to assure proper backups. I usually set up my backup systems with some shell code, with a little help from [backupninja](https://labs.riseup.net/code/projects/backupninja) for the database dumps.

For MediaWiki systems it makes sense to "split up" the backup in different parts. I prefer to

0. move code into `htdocs` or `html` directory
1. keep code in a git repository at GitHub (excluding images and dumps),
2. nightly dump database into a directory not accessible through webserver (e.g. Apache)
3. `rsync` everything to somewhere else
4. I have a `scripts` directory to manage all this

I'm also running several MediaWiki instances from one code base. I might open up some of this code if there's enough interest (from me or others).

Comment: For running multiple MediaWiki instances, how to keep the sharable configuration choices synced across these instances?  When making a change in LocalSettings.php, do you manually do the same change in LocalSettings.php for all the MW instances?

Comment: Shared stuff is the same, stuff that differs I keep in `$wgFarmVariables = array('1.example.com' => array(
'sharedUsers' => true), '2.example.com' => array('wgFarmSemantic' => true));`, which I then run through `if (array_key_exists(wiki_yt_host(), $wgFarmVariables)) {
  foreach ($wgFarmVariables[wiki_yt_host()] as $name => $value) {
    $$name = $value;
  }
}`. (You're welcome to ask another question about this for follow up.)